# Does The Unit Of Work Make Sense with Clean Architecture(DDD) Or Just The Repository Is Enough?

Tags: domain-driven-design, unit-of-work, clean-architecture, specification-pattern

I want to ask if it make sense to use the unit of work with repositories on a project following the domain driven design philosophy and clean architecture or it doesn't make more sense and the generic repository pattern is sufficient?

Answer (score 8):

Martin Fowler describes a [Unit of Work](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) as

> Maintains a list of objects affected by a business transaction and coordinates the writing out of changes and the resolution of concurrency problems.

The Unit of Work pattern is listed under "Chapter 11: [Object-Relational Behavioral Patterns](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/index.html)" in his book. Thus it applies to the implementation of a repository.

In DDD you define aggregates and you usually pass the aggregate root to a repository to save it. Now it's up to the repository implementation if it uses a unit of work, because it must coordinate the execution of multiple statements send to the db, or not. Maybe you are using a document oriented NoSQL db and just post the serialized aggregate. In this case you don't have to coordinate actions, because there is only one update action - a
put request.

I think that the Unit of Work pattern still makes sense in a clean architecture, but only in the repository implementation.

Comment: Thanks Rene. Make sense

Comment: Thank you Rene. I went down a wormhole trying to answer this question and I think this is a great answer. if one uses a database that can save an aggregate without an impedence mismatch issue, then you never need a UnitOfWork class in your repository. If you are using a SQL database while trying to save a complex aggregate, then maybe the UnitOfWork can help with coordination. But I guess one can say that using a non SQL db is fantastic for DDD since we can easily just serialize the aggregate. Did I get that right @Rene Link?

Comment: @alaboudi yes, that is what i want to say.